# Understanding scaleEffect in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

The following code animates the size of an image as soon as it loads, it animates it from half of its size to its full size, but there is something I don't fully understand about the parameters in `scaleFactor`.

Can someone explain the parameter inside the `scaleEffect` modifier?

1. How come it can take a Boolean parameter?
2. How is it possible to enter a scale range `1.0 : 0.5` parameter?
3. What does the `?` do?

As far as I can see the `scaleEffect` modifier only takes two parameters, a `CGFloat` and a `UnitPoint`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scaleFactor = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("top-image")
                .scaleEffect(scaleFactor ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
                .onAppear() {
                    self.scaleFactor = true
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several declared overloaded scaleEffect

> ```
> extension View {
>
>     @inlinable public func scaleEffect(_ scale: CGSize, anchor: UnitPoint = .center) -> some View
>
>     @inlinable public func scaleEffect(_ s: CGFloat, anchor: UnitPoint = .center) -> some View
>
>     @inlinable public func scaleEffect(x: CGFloat = 0.0, y: CGFloat = 0.0, anchor: UnitPoint = .center) -> some View
> }
> ```

In the example in question it is used second one, so it is actually

```
        Image("top-image")
            .scaleEffect(scaleFactor ? 1.0 : 0.5, anchor: .center)
```

which is documented as

> Scales this view’s rendered output by the given amount in both the
>   horizontal and vertical directions, relative to an anchor point.

and `scaleFactor ? 1.0 : 0.5` means just in-place ternary operator for first `scale` parameter which applied either 1.0 (identity) or 0.5 (half) depending on corresponding view state.

Comment: Thank you for touching on ternary operators, that was a big part if my confusion.